# Complex derivatives of line integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $O$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (the complex plane), and let $g : O \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function that satisfies the differential equation $g^{\prime\prime}(z) - zg(z) = 0$ for every $z \in O$. Prove that for all differentiable curves $U$ in $O$ with the same endpoints, the value $$\int_U g(x)^2 dx$$ is the same.

Comment: Where did you come across this? It seems like it might be homework... So, where are you stuck?

Comment: not even sure where to begin :-S

Comment: The differential equation in question is the [Airy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function). Its two linear independent solutions (functions $\mathrm{Ai}(z)$ and $\mathrm{Bi}(z)$) are holomorphic on the whole complex plane. Hence $g(z)^2$ is also a holomorphic function and the integral has the same value by the residue theorem.

Answer (score 6):

It suffices to show the integral is zero when the contour is a closed curve. Let $\gamma:[a, b] \to O$ be a closed curve. Integration by parts (with $u = g(z)^2$ and $dv = dz$), then using the differential equation gives
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \limits _{\gamma} g(z)^2 \text{ }dz
&=& (g(z))^2 z\Bigg|^{\gamma(b)}_{\gamma(a)}
  - \int \limits _{\gamma} 2g(z) g'(z) z \text{ }dz \\
&=& (g(z))^2 z\Bigg|^{\gamma(b)}_{\gamma(a)}
  - \int \limits _{\gamma} 2 g'(z) g''(z) \text{ }dz \\
&=& (g(z))^2 z\Bigg|^{\gamma(b)}_{\gamma(a)}
  - (g'(z))^2 \Bigg|^{\gamma(b)}_{\gamma(a)} \\
&=& 0 - 0 = 0
\end{eqnarray} 
since $\gamma(b) = \gamma(a)$.